# Umbraco CheckBox Picker

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I was wondering if there is any Tree Picker similar to the old uComponents checkbox Picker.

[image]

Something just like a mutli node tree picker that show the tree structure. (It can just be the parent of the picked item)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not with that UI that I'm aware of. You'd have to either code something like that yourself as a custom property editor, or you could just use the built in multi-node tree picker, which offers the same functionality, it's just a different UI.

Comment: I have lost quite some time trying to make mine, but i did not suceeded.